# Autodesk Forge Modify your Models tutorial, no existing activities to select from

Tags: autodesk-forge

I followed all the steps on the tutorial and everything else seems to be working fine but there are no options to select from on the dropdown for the exisiting activities on the app. 
Do I need to change any of the code in the "Define an Activity" section? At the moment I've just copy pasted everything in the tutorial ( https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/designautomation/activity/netcore)

Comment: No change is needed, maybe the code was placed in the incorrect location, you can always compare it with the final version of the tutorial that can be found here. https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/blob/master/forgesample/Controllers/DesignAutomationController.cs#L46

Comment: Thanks - but even when i download the full project from that github link none of the buttons on the app seem to work, I have no idea where i'm going wrong (very new to this stuff) - I think maybe the tutorials assume a lot of prior knowledge and I'm missing something that should be obvious

Comment: I can help, send me your Timezone and availability so we can do a screen-share call. feel free to email me jaime.rosales.duque@autodesk.com I'm EST based in NYC.